# Модульное программирование PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

Не так давно решил создать небольшой двиг для быстрой разработки сайтов под себя, чтобы не надо было доделывать: было все готово, только подключай модули и плагины...

И вот в общем-то проблема, никак не могу придумать, как бы лучше. Есть папки

```
-admin
-ModAndPlugin
```

В папке `-admin` есть файл, который сканирует папку `-ModAndPlugin` и получает массив из вложенных в нее папок

```
array([0]=>"./ModAndPlugin/user/" , [1]=>"./ModAndPlugin/maillent/")
```

Как подключить модули?

Дайте ссылки на темы, где уже такое обсуждалось, или готовый кусок кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы вам не хранить модули и плагины в папке, а в бд их описывать, а ссылками их подключать?
Пример :

/system/exts/mod/modulename/index.php
/system/exts/pls/pluginname/index.php

ссылка : ?module=modulename

и как вариант его подключения с защитой от произвольного запуска функций :

```
//$allow_func - массив из имён функций, которые можно запускать
$allow_func['show_page']        =   'ok';
$allow_func['users']        =   'ok';
#
if (!function_exists($module)) {
    if (@file_exists("./system/extensions/modules/$module/$module".'.php')) {
        include "./system/extensions/modules/$module/$module".'.php';
        $allow_func[$module]    =   'ok';//если модуль существует, то подключить и добавить в список разрешённых для запуска функций
    } else {
        return '<strong>Модуль не подключен123</strong><br />';
    }
}
if ($allow_func[$module] == 'ok') {
    $module();
}
```

Comment: о, пишем джумлу с нуля)

Comment: Эх, а я так надеялся, что мой метод хоть чуточку уникален)

Answer (score 2):

```
function __autoload($className){
  $filename = "-ModAndPlugin/".$className.".class.php";
  if(!file_exists($filename)){
    die("lack of required module");
  }else{
    include $filename;
  }
}
```

И ничего не надо городить лишнего.
При обращении к конструктору несуществующего класса, его файл будет пытаться подгрузиться.